# Instagram API: does the /users/self/media/recent endpoint have a time limit?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to iterate over all Instagram posts (with count = 8) for a user which has 24 posts. The first result returns 8 posts and the following pagination object:

```
Request:
{ count: 8, max_id: undefined }

Response:
results =  8
pagination = {
  next_url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/991120266/media/recent?access_token=TOKEN&count=8&max_id=653406866835254619_991120266',
  next_max_id: '653406866835254619_991120266',
}

Request:
{ count: 8, max_id: '653406866835254619_991120266' }

Response:
results =  8
pagination =  {
  next_url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/991120266/media/recent?access_token=TOKEN&count=8&max_id=653404659733769534_991120266',
  next_max_id: '653404659733769534_991120266',
 }

Request:
{ count: 8, max_id: '653404659733769534_991120266' }

Response:
results =  4
pagination =  {}
```

It correctly fetches the user's 16 latest Instagram post, but on the last request, it only returns 4 posts and omits the oldest 4 posts. Why doesn't Instagram return those last 4 posts? I've also tried setting "count" to 30 but it still only returns the same 20 results. I also tried setting `min_id` to 0 instead of `max_id` but it also won't return those posts.

Answer (score 2):

Oops, I was using a Sandbox app which is limited to 20 results per user! Solution: get app approved to get out of sandbox.

Comment: Once you left Sandbox mode, are you able to get all of the user's past media?